# How to Implement a UILongPressGesture followed by Swipe gesture in ios

Tags: ios, uiswipegesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am trying to implement the LongPress Gesture followed by Swipe Gesture on a Button in ios. The view would more likely to be the "Slide to Cancel" and Record feature of WhatsApp application.

Currently i am not receiving swipe gesture event. 
I am implementing shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer method also. Please suggest.

```
(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *) recognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We dont need a separate Swipe Gesture Recognizer. The different states in Long Press Gesture Recognizer can be used to handle this scenario.

Long Press Gesture has different states Like **UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan**, **UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged** and **UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded**.

**UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan** gets called as soon as you long press the subview.

**UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged** gets called when the user tries to move the finger .

**UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded** gets called when the user lifts the finger from the touch point.

```
- (void)longPressGestureForPreviewImageView:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        // Long press detected, start the timer
        [self showPreviewImage:recognizer];
    }
    else if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        NSLog(@"Swipe up");

        if ([self.thumbnailImageView.gestureRecognizers containsObject:recognizer]) {
            [self.thumbnailImageView removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        }
    }
    else if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [self hidePreviewImage];
    }
```

So we can use the Gesture Delegate methods to handle the swipe along with a Long Press Gesture Recognizer.